# permission denied to create pg_catalog.sample_table using spring-boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using `Spring-boot` and configured database in `application.properties` file like below

```
spring.datasource.primary.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.primary.username=postgres
spring.datasource.primary.password=pass
spring.datasource.primary.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.primary.maxActive=10
spring.datasource.primary.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.primary.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default-schema=public
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto:update
```

**It works perfect in windows**, but when I run it in Mac it shows some errors and does not create table

```
[ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000388: Unsuccessful:
    create table sample_table (table_id  serial not null, name varchar(255))
2017-07-07 10:52:51.145 ERROR 1446 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  :
    ERROR: permission denied to create "pg_catalog.sample_table"
Detail: System catalog modifications are currently disallowed.
```

I tried below things to resolve the issue

- By changing default schema in properties to something else.
- By changing `ddl-auto` to `create`, `create-drop` and `none`.

but have no success.

**I don't know why it is trying to create table in `pg_catalog` schema?**

Comment: looks like  configuration problem in postgresql rather than hibernate. Maybe the schema is misconfigured.

Comment: I grant all permissions to `postgres` user..

Comment: you do not have mydb in you your postgres

Comment: @Generic it is present..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by changing below line from `application.properties` file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default-schema=public
```

to

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public
```

and it worked.