# How to fix this query in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

So I have this query as below :

```
/**
 * @param partnerId .
 * @return Notification
 */
@Query("SELECT p FROM PartnerNotification p "
        + "INNER JOIN account AS account " + "WHERE account.accountId = :partnerId ")
 PartnerNotification findNotificationByPartnerId(@Param("partnerId") Integer partnerId);
```

where I am trying to select all the column in partner notification  @Entity
where partner id is equal with the parameter.
partner_id  is a foreign key at my table so at my entities I have :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
private Account account;
```

and maybe here is the problem any way I have tried to test some idea I had but as is the first time there I could not find what's is wrong.

SO i have tried :

```
//    /**
//     * @param partnerId partnerId.
//     * @return PartnerNotification
//     */
//    PartnerNotification findNotificationByPartnerId(Integer partnerId);

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
private Account account;

/**
 * @param partnerId .
 * @return Notification
 */
@Query("SELECT p FROM PartnerNotification p "
        + "JOIN p.account acc WHERE acc.accountId = :partnerId ")
 PartnerNotification findNotificationByPartnerId(@Param("partnerId") Integer partnerId);
```

and

```
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private Account account;
```

Comment: change fetch type of Account to Eager : @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

Comment: ok I will try, nope still I get an error but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```java
@Query(SELECT p FROM PartnerNotification p JOIN p.account acc WHERE acc.accountId = :partnerId)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: your solution seems good to me ,  i tired and i got
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42501
ERROR: permission denied for table notification

Comment: okay the error does not look like it from query, can you try fetching all the data using `notificationrepo.findAll()`, just for testing. Because it looks like [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963140/permission-denied-to-create-pg-catalog-sample-table-using-spring-boot)

Comment: I tired a normal select as the other suggest and I get an error, partner_id is not compatible with the account

Comment: can you add both the models

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need any custom query.

```java
List<PartnerNotification> findByAccountId(Integer partnerId);
```

Comment: in fact, I don't want a list  but I will try it

Comment: then apply limit also

Comment: @IliaTapia According to your model, if you don't want a list so you need to specify some criteria. The relation between `PartnerNotification` and `Account` is one-to-many

Comment: I tried this and got: No property partnerId found for type PartnerNotification!

Comment: @IliaTapia I believe you tried another thing no the same as my answer

Comment: no, I tried but really did not work, I want that this work also mate I would be happy for that